# redirecting a html page to a php page using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

M stuck in redirecting a html page to a php page..and can I perform that using anchor tag? If not can someone give me code to redirect it using some javascript or jquery? I never learnt Javascript or jquery.please help me..
here's the piece of code

```
<li><a href="previous.php" style="text-decoration:none">Previous</a></li>
```

Comment: Is previous.php at the same location as your html page? What is happening when you click on the link?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any extra codes in this. Your present code should work.

If not working still, please check and let us know below few.

1. Where is these files (html and php) located ? (webserver?)
2. Different folders?
3. what is the error while clicking on the link you get?

Upon these answers, we may help you..

Answer (score 0):

javascript code place this in your html head

```
<script>
  function openPage(){
    window.open("previous.php","_self")
  };
</script>
```

edit the html with this

```
 <li><a href="previous.php" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="openPage()">Previous</a></li>
```

Comment: where do I put this brother? @meenesh jain

Comment: @meenesh create  script tag and place it within your script tag